# How to get Python csv.writer & csv.writerows to write to next lines, instead one under the other

Tags: python, csv, reader, writer

I'm trying to get Python to write 5 lines of text to a CSV file, but to rewrite individual values into cells next to and not under.

At the moment the program is able to write all the variables, values as it wants but not properly arranged. However, csv.write and csv.writerows keeps overwriting from cell so that it adds values to cell [A1] then [A2] and not to [A1] then [B1].
Is there a function that I can use that
writes everything on line like for example print(f"{variable}", end=', ')

I am very new to python sorry.

filename= 'test1.csv'

with open (filename, mode="w") as file:
writer = csv.writer(file)

```
with open('1.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    categories = data['categories']
    writer.writerow(f"URL,{','.join(categories)}") 
for file in json_files:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.load(f)                                               
        writer.writerow(url)    
    for category in data['categories']:
        scores = data['categories'][category]['score']                                                        
        writer.writerow(f"{scores}")
```

```
**# Desired output:
# 
# ,
# 
# URL,performance,accessibility,best-practices,seo,pwa,visibility,security,ads,mobile
# URL, 0.23, 0.56, 0.57, 0.67, 0.31, 0.67, 0.37, 0.54, 0.71,
# URL, 0.53, 0.53, 0.57, 0.8, 0.23, 0.67, 0.5, 0.62, 0.71,
# URL, 1, 1, 0.86, 0.88, 0.58, 0.67, 0.42, 0.38, 1,
# 
# 
# 
# What ive got
# 
# U,R,L,",",p,e,r,f,o,r,m,a,n,c,e,",",a,c,c,e,s,s,i,b,i,l,i,t,y,",",b,e,s,t,-,p,r,a,c,t,i,c,e,s,",",s,e,o,",",p,w,a,",",v,i,s,i,b,i,l,i,t,y,",",s,e,c,u,r,i,t,y,",",a,d,s,",",m,o,b,i,l,e
# 
# URL
# 
# 0,.,2,3
# 
# 0,.,5,6
# 
# 0,.,5,7
# 
# 0,.,6,7
# 
# 0,.,3,1
# 
# 0,.,6,7
# 
# 0,.,3,7
# 
# 0,.,5,4
# 
# 0,.,7,1
# 
# URL
# 
# 0,.,5,3
# 
# 0,.,5,3
# 
# 0,.,5,7
# 
# 0,.,8
# 
# 0,.,2,3
# 
# 0,.,6,7
# 
# 0,.,5
# 
# 0,.,6,2
# 
# 0,.,7,1
# 
# URL
# 
# 1
# 
# 1
# 
# 0,.,8,6
# 
# 0,.,8,8
# 
# 0,.,5,8
# 
# 0,.,6,7
# 
# 0,.,4,2
# 
# 0,.,3,8
# 
# 1
**
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the `.json` files you use as input?

Comment: they look the same as you suggested but some have more I think this one are objects in themselves and there just the result

Comment: If you see my code, you can see that categories are as one object in it are these objects as categories and to them only assigned variables with the result sorry to be so late

Comment: Hi, and welcome . To be able to offer any help [we need to see what you see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), what you're dealing with. Please edit your post and include a few lines from the input JSON files so that we can offer some help.

Answer (score -1):

I assumed that your `json` files were structured as follow (with only one JSON object per `json` file):

```
{
    "URL": <url_content>,
    "performance": <performance_score>,
    "accessibility": <accessibility_score>,
    ...
}
```

I came up with this code:

```py
import json

files = ["1.json", "2.json"]
output = "output.csv"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    aggregate = []

    for file in files:
        with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
            curr_data = json.load(fp)
        if len(aggregate) == 0:
            aggregate.append(",".join([f"{key}" for key in curr_data]))
        aggregate.append(",".join([f"{curr_data[key]}" for key in curr_data]))

    with open(output, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write("\n".join(aggregate))
```

I created two dummy `json` files:
`1.json`

```
{
  "URL": "url1_content",
  "performance": 0.23,
  "accessibility": 0.56
}
```

`2.json`

```
{
  "URL": "url2_content",
  "performance": 0.53,
  "accessibility": 0.53
}
```

This then creates the following `output.csv`:

```
URL,performance,accessibility
url1_content,0.23,0.56
url2_content,0.53,0.58
```

Comment: could you only tell me how can i take accurate objects to output.csv bcs in my .jsons there are multiple objects that i dont need as you can see on my code, I guess that's kinda stupid questions but im really new in python but still got task like this

Comment: Do you know the csv module and its DictWriter class? It offers a very straightforward way to convert "flat JSON objects" like you've shown to CSV rows. Trying to manually encode CSV will almost certainly lead to errors. I recommend encouraging using the very correct/robust csv encoders/decoders.